# Group By using all column from left table after join with replicated names in pyspark data frame

Tags: join, group-by, pyspark, alias, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark DataFrame obtained by joining two table. They share the column "name

```
valuesA = [('A',1,5),('B',7,12),('C',3,6),('D',4,9)]
TableA = spark.createDataFrame(valuesA,['name','id', 'otherValue']).alias('ta')

valuesB = [('A',1),('A',4),('B',2),('B',8),('E',4)]
TableB = spark.createDataFrame(valuesB,['name','id']).alias('tb')

joined = TableA.join(TableB, TableA.name==TableB.name, 'left')
```

I would like to do something similar to a select  `joined.select('ta.*').show()` for groupby but `joined.groupBy('ta.*').count()` raises an error.

How can I implement something like that without having to explicitly list the columns? `joined.groupBy(TableA.columns).count()` raises issue because "name" is not unique

As an alternative how can I retrieve the column with proper alias from joined?

PS Doing the join as `joined = TableA.join(TableB, ['name'], 'left')` is not a useful solution because I have columns that are not used in the join condition that have the same name in table A and B

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a list comprehension to get a list of column names for the groupBy:

```
aliasListTableA = ['ta.' + c for c in TableA.columns]
joined.groupBy(aliasListTableA).count().show()
```

Output:

```
+----+---+----------+-----+
|name| id|otherValue|count|
+----+---+----------+-----+
|   B|  7|        12|    2|
|   D|  4|         9|    1|
|   C|  3|         6|    1|
|   A|  1|         5|    2|
+----+---+----------+-----+
```

In general I try to avoid [alias](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.alias) as it hides the origin of a column:

```
aliasListTableA = ['ta_' + c for c in TableA.columns]
aliasListTableB = ['tb_' + c for c in TableB.columns]

joined = joined.toDF(*(aliasListTableA + aliasListTableB))
joined.show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+-----+-------------+-------+-----+
|ta_name|ta_id|ta_otherValue|tb_name|tb_id|
+-------+-----+-------------+-------+-----+
|      B|    7|           12|      B|    2|
|      B|    7|           12|      B|    8|
|      D|    4|            9|   null| null|
|      C|    3|            6|   null| null|
|      A|    1|            5|      A|    1|
|      A|    1|            5|      A|    4|
+-------+-----+-------------+-------+-----+
```

Comment: I tought about this approach, the problem with this is that is quite annoying if I need to do that multiple times during the analysis I will end up with ugly column names or I have to clean it after every join - group by operation